# How can I exclude a hover effect with CSS

Tags: html, css, class

I've written some code so a desc box will pop up when you scroll over an image, however the way it's CSS is set up I have to include the popup box in the hover class, which means when you move off the base image onto the box it stays, how can I change this so the box goes away after moving the cursor from the icon image.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 

p { margin-top: -6px; }

h1.d1 {
    color: #0195d3;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family:"Veranda",Arial;
    letter-spacing:.8px;
    text-align:left;
    }

p.d2 {
    color:#c8c8c8;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family:"Veranda",Arial;
    letter-spacing:.05px;
    line-height:100%;
    text-align:left;
    }

.desc{
    background: black;
    opacity: .85;
    height: 140px;
    width: 180px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: -100px;
    left:-20px;
    display:none;
    padding:1px 20px;

}
.desc:after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-5px;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    background:black;
    left:20%;
    margin-left:-10px;
    -moz-transform:rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
    transform:rotate(45deg);
}
.icon {
    margin:200px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.icon:hover .desc{
    display:block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="icon">
<img src="Images/Icon/Vault.png">
<div class="desc">
<h1 class="d1">Vault</h1>
<p class="d2">9/24/13</p>
<p class="d2">Who knew a 2D platformer could also be an epic RPG quest?  
Vault is about exploration and...</p>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> which means when you move off the base image onto the box it stays, how can I change this so the box goes away after moving the cursor from the icon image.

By simple telling it to disappear again when it itself gets hovered:

```
.icon .desc:hover { display:none; }
```

But be aware that this might lead to a “flicker” effect if it disappearing leaves the cursor over the image again, because that will trigger the box to become visible again … so this works only really well if the box does not overlap the image.

http://jsfiddle.net/XVgcT/